Battery discharge over time
I noticed that my laptop battery percentage drops faster at low percentages. I am wondering why.
For instance, the drop from 20 to 0 is much faster than the drop from 100 to 80 percent.
I've heard that the voltage of batteries tend to drop when the battery power is low.
Would this be the cause?

Why is kind of a chemistry question. Depending on what chemistry the battery is using charge/discharge curves look different. Depending on how old it is, it will have either NiMH or Li/Ion. Both have steep discharge curves when near empty.

Unfortunately, estimating remaining charge left in a battery or cell is not as simple as monitoring the fuel level in a liquid fuel tank. A battery's voltage remains close to nominal voltage during most of the discharge cycle and then rapidly falls off at the end. This means that monitoring the battery voltage doesn't give an accurate reading of the state of charge until the rapid decrease starts. Some better systems will monitor the charge in and out of the battery (mathematically integrating current × time) to keep track of the energy contained. Very smart systems will then learn the effective capacity over a few charge / discharge cycles and the display will be adjusted accordingly.

I am wondering why. For instance, the drop from 20 to 0 is much faster than the drop from 100 to 80 percent.

It's being optimistic! And when the voltage really starts to fall it rapidly updates the state of charge to a more realistic value.

I've heard that the voltage of batteries tend to drop when the battery power is low. Would this be the cause?

Yes.
